# How do I filter duplicates from a sharepoint list using ssis

Tags: ssis

I have successfully connected a sql data base to a sharepoint list using ssis.  The problem is that every time I run the project all the data gets dumped into the list and causes duplicates.  Is there a way to not import the duplicate entries?

Answer (score 0):

You could pull it into a temporary table and run an 'UPSERT' set of statements to get the new records into the table.

If you are on sql 2008, you could use the new MERGE functionality.

An UPSERT consists of an INSERT for new records, UPDATES for existing rows that need to reflect changes in the source and DELETES if desired.

You can do this in a stored procedure which you can call from a execute SQL step.